# Exit tmux but stay in terminal

Tags: terminal, tmux

How can I exit a Tmux session but at the same time still able to stay in the terminal window? in other words, when I exit the session I get the terminal prompt. The problem is when I exit a Tumax session, the terminal closes and I want both together to work at the same time, so I can do work on both of them. I need both together, so I can finish work on Tumax and also at the same time of terminal.

Comment: how did you start Tmux?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to detach from your session, then this can be accomplished in Tmux through `<tmux-prefix>d`, where Tmux leader is usually bound to the keys <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>, or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>.

This will put the session in the background, but it will not close it. You can then just exit from the terminals in Tmux as well, which will end the session and exit Tmux.

Also, You can do `<tmux-prefix>:kill-session<enter>`, which will kill the session.

If you start Tmux with `tmux new-session`, you can exit to your terminal directly when you exit the session.